# Pourquoi ajouter « s » à un adverbe tel que « jusque » ?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, histoire, accord

L'exemple est :

> Mais que, pour toutes les opinions que j'ai reçues jusques alors en ma
>   créance, je ne pouvais mieux faire que d'entreprendre.

Pourquoi un *s* a-t-il été ajouté à « jusque**s** » ?

Comment: Je suggère que tu poses une deuxième question pour l'emploi de "que" si besoin, deux problèmes entièrement différents.

Comment: À la scène 1 acte 1 de Dom Juan écrit par le fidèle Molière autrement dit Jean-Baptiste Poquelin, Sganarelle (le précieux valet) énonce vers 45 "un chapitre à durer jusques au soir"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'orthographe habituelle de **jusque** de nos jours est effectivement sans *s*. **Jusque** vient du latin *usque* qui n'a pas de s final.

En ancien français comme beaucoup d'adverbes venant du latin avaient un *s* final on a ajouté aussi un *s* final à des adverbes, mais aussi des prépositions et conjonctions, qui n'auraient pas dû en avoir d'après leur étymologie. C'est ce qui est arrivé à la préposition *jusque*. Ce *s* (appelé *s adverbial*) était courant dans la langue classique (voir par exemple les dramaturges du 17<sup>e</sup> siècle) mais n'apparaît plus de nos jours sauf dans une langue très soutenue et uniquement quand *jusques* est placé devant une voyelle et alors il faut faire la liaison.

L'emploi du mot *créance* employé dans le sens de *croyance* dans la phrase citée dénote un texte classique et donc l'orthographe de *jusques* n'est pas étonnante dans ce contexte. Le texte fait penser à Descartes, et de fait cette phrase est extraite du *[Discours sur la méthode](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/13846/13846-h/13846-h.htm)*. L'orthographe de certains mots a été modernisée, le transcripteur a laissé le *s* à *jusques* mais aurait aussi pu le retirer.

J'ai eu un peu de mal à trouver un texte contemporain employant l'orthographe  *jusques* et je l'ai trouvé chez un poète : Serge Gainsbourg.

> Jusques en haut des cuisses
>   Elle est bottée

(*Initiales BB*)

Answer (score 1):

*[Le littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/jusques)* en ligne donne l'emploi de *jusques*

Ci-après celui téléchargé qui donne plus d'exemples pour différencier les usages :

> **JUSQUE** et **JUSQUES** [*ju-sk'*. On n'écrit *jusques* que devant
>   des voyelles, soit en vers pour avoir une syllabe de plus, soit en
>   prose pour l'euphonie, et alors l'*s* se lie : *ju-ske-z* à quand....
>   
>  D'après Chifflet, Gramm. p. 236, il était indifférent de
>   prononcer ou de ne pas prononcer l'*s* de jusque ; pour le XVIe
>   siècle. Palsgrave dit qu'on prononçait juque] prép.
>
> **3°**  Avec quand, jusque ou *jusques* prend à.
>  ♦ Jusques à
>   quand serai-je dans le trouble et en de si cruelles agitations ?,
>   BOURDAL., Exhort. sur l'observ. des règles, t. I, p. 217 
> ♦ Jusqu'à
>   quand serez-vous emporté par vos passions ?, FLÉCH., I, 15
>  ♦
>   Jusqu'à quand souffre-t-on que ce peuple respire ?, RAC., Esth. II,
>   1
>  ♦ Insensé, jusqu'à quand chercheras-tu des plaisirs qui ne
>   peuvent te rendre heureux ?, MASS., Avent, Bonh. des justes. 
> ♦
>   *Jusques* à quand, Romains, Voulez-vous profaner tous les droits des
>   humains ?, VOLT., Brut. v, 2 
>   **4°**  Avec aujourd'hui, on ne
>   met pas la préposition à.
>  ♦ Et *jusques* aujourd'hui Je l'ai pressé
>   de feindre et j'ai parlé pour lui, RAC., Bajaz. I, 4
>  ♦ Aucuns
>   monstres par moi domptés jusque aujourd'hui Ne m'ont donné le droit de
>   faillir comme lui, RAC., Phèdre, I, 1