# Jusques à quand

Tags: vocabulaire, prononciation

The Louis Segond translation of [Matthew 17:17](http://saintebible.com/matthew/17-17.htm) is the first place I've seen « jusques » :

[image: Jusques à quand]

Ngrams [suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jusqu%27%C3%A0%2Cjusques%20%C3%A0&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cjusqu%27%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjusqu%27%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJusqu%27%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cjusques%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjusques%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJusques%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0) that it's out of use and Wiktionary [says](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jusques) it's *vieilli*.

Wiktionary also says it's paragogic and pronounced /ʒys.kə.z‿/, with which one dictionary entry [agrees](http://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition.php?mot=jusques), and the TLF has [similar notes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jusques):

> *jusques* devant voyelle par raison d'euphonie : *jusques à quand*? *jusques aujourd'hui*, *jusques à hier*, *jusques à tantôt*, etc.

Google Translate on the other hand probably foolishly [pronounces it](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/jusques%20%C3%A0%20quand) without liaison, as though there were no "s". Larousse's online edition [redirects](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/jusque/45224/locution?q=jusques#16001744) to *jusque* or suggests the fixed expression *jusques et y compris*, without a pronunciation guide. A couple of other dictionaries omit the word altogether.

**Question:** Is it then right to say that *jusques à quand* is pronounced /ʒys.kə.za.kɑ̃/ ?

**Question:** Will I see such expressions anywhere outside old-fashioned translations of the Bible?

Comment: B.B. Initials de Gainsbourg: "Jusques en haut des cuisses elle est bottée, et c'est comme un calice à sa beauté". La chanson n'est guère si vieille !

Comment: @Chewie Neither is [La ronde des jurons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8Wawyse7vY) much more than a half-century old, but I don't take it for my phrasebook of gros mots ;) But the point is taken!

Comment: Would you consider your question is a dupe to [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8395/358)? There's nothing about pronunciation in my answer, I would add it depends if you need to liaise and add an extra syllable, in poetry for example.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8395/358

Comment: @Laure Hmm.. If I'd found that before asking this, I would probably have asked two extra questions in the comments: how it affects pronunciation, and what it looks like before "à" — I would be puzzled by "jusques alors" since I didn't know that existed... which has nothing to do with dupe status, of course :p Those questions could probably have been answered in the comments. I'm easy either way.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Anyway I downvoted the accepted answer,  the s is not there "only for additionnal prononciation", it has nothing to do with the pronunciation. And it is possible to find the use of *jusques* in 20th century literature. The other answer at least, does not say anything wrong.

Comment: @Laure Fair enough. Not sure where to go from here but unaccepted it...

Answer (score 3):

The only "not so awkward" use of `jusques` in nowaday language would be in the expression `jusques et y compris`, which means `until and including`.
And yes, it is said `\ʒys.kə.z‿e i kɔ̃.pʁi\`.

Any other use would be very dated, or poetic. The use in `Initials B.B.` mentioned above was clearly to fit the song's rythm (one syllable more with the "s")

Answer (score 2):

***Question:*** Is it then right to say that jusques à quand is pronounced /ʒys.kə.za.kɑ̃/ ?

Yes I think so, actually the +s is here only for additionnal prononciation.

***Question:*** Will I see such expressions anywhere outside old-fashioned translations of the Bible?

Probably in several other old texts. It is never used nowadays, except rarely in some poetry.

About this :

- [Pourquoi ajouter « s » à un adverbe tel que « jusque » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8395/pourquoi-ajouter-s-%C3%A0-un-adverbe-tel-que-jusque)
- http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-jusque-jusqu-a-jusqu-hier-jusques-jusques-et-y-compris-jusques-a-quand-jusqu-a-ce-que-111202968.html

Comment: Saying "the +s is here only for additional pronunciation." is not correct. This "s" is  called "adverbial s" and was added to some words (adverbs,  prepositions...) (*encores, mêmes, presques*, etc.) that didn't have one by analogy to those adverbs (and there are several)  that had one because of their Latin etymology (*plus, moins, certes*, etc.)